# Why the .exe file that uses Speech Recognition created using pyinstaller is not running?

Tags: python, pip, speech-recognition, pyinstaller, pyaudio

I created a simple python program which recognizes speech. I used Speech Recognition module for the purpose. For the purpose of using this module I needed the pyAudio module. I was unable to install pyAudio. Every time I used `pip install pyaudio` the console was throwing an error, so someone in stack overflow suggested me to use:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

The installation was successful and the program worked fine. I used the pyinstaller module to create a .exe file of the program. The file creation was successful. But when I ran the .exe file, the command line appeared for a second and then suddenly it disappeared. I used the Command Prompt to run the .exe file and I am getting this error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'
[10800] Failed to execute script program